# Filtering a column to use in a calculated field in Quicksight

Tags: calculated-field, amazon-quicksight

I have a table like this:

| group | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |

I want to create a calculated field that is the value of A divided by the value of B (2/3).

In PowerBI I could create two measures storing the values of A and B and then divide those measures.

How can I do that in Quicksight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do create two sums, one for each group, and then do the final calculation

Add a calculated field called `Sum A`

```
sumOver(ifelse(group='A', value, null), [], PRE_AGG)
```

Add a calculated field called `Sum B`

```
sumOver(ifelse(group='B', value, null), [], PRE_AGG)
```

Add the last calculated field for you final calculation:

```
{Sum A} / {Sum B}
```